# How to print all auto suggested elements using selenium

Tags: selenium, printing, element

I have been trying to print all auto suggested elements by google. But when i print the auto suggested keywords are not displayed. I should get 10 results as per image attached and print it.

Below is my code:

```
'''
package FindElements;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Selenium_Vaibhav\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");

        List<WebElement> list= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='selenium']"));
        System.out.println(list.size());


        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
}

'''
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspected the search result element, you'll notice that all the list elements share a class in common, which is "sbl1", try this solution :

```
List<WebElement> list= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='sbl1']"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but getting 0 result. Not fetching auto suggested elements.

Comment: i'm sorry, i made a mistake. The xpath worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Store the index in WebElement and then store the text in String variable. You will get the all 10 keywords

```
for(int i=0; i<=lists;i++) {
    WebElement searchtexets=list.get(i);
    String Searchtexts=searchtexets.getText();
    System.out.println(Searchtexts);
}
```